# Algorithm to match query to known list, presenting result based on lexicographic order

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I am designing an algorithm to find strings in a list given a query and return whichever string in the list matches the query. This is to answer based on the first match in lexicographic order. If the query is an empty string I return an empty string and if the query is not something that any item in the known list starts with I return `-1`. Here is my algorithm so far. Is there any way I can modify my algorithm so that it runs faster?

example input:

```
usernames: ["jBlame", "jannet"]
queries: ["j", "jm", "jbl", "JB"]
```

example output:

```
jannet
-1
jBlame
jBlame
```

Here is my current implementation. I have been racking my brains trying to find a way to increase this code's speed, but I am not finding a way.

```
def name_finder(usernames, queries):
    users = sorted(usernames,key=lambda m:m.upper())
    for q in queries:
        if q=='':
            print ''
            break
        for user in users:
            if q.upper()==user.upper()[:len(q)]: 
                print user
                break
        else: print -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a **Speed-time tradeoff**. Build an index first, which costs more space and some time. Use that index for query, every `find_name()` call will gain the benefit of O(1) time complexity then.

```
usernames = ["jBlame", "jannet"]
queries = ["j", "jm", "jbl", "JB"]

def build_index(usernames):
    """Build an index by given usernames

    :returns: index dict
    """
    result = {}
    # Sort should ignore cases
    for username in sorted(usernames, key=lambda x: x.lower()):
        for i in range(len(username)):
            # TODO: If you only want the first result matched, modify this line to 
            # let the index consumes less space
            result.setdefault(username[:(i + 1)].lower(), []).append(username)
    return result


def find_name(query, index):
    """return the matched username by given query and index
    """
    if not query:
        return ''
    result = index.get(query.lower())
    return result[0] if result else -1

index = build_index(usernames)
for query in queries:
    print find_name(query, index)
```

Comment: Let k= number of queries and n = number of usernames, and s= average length of each username entry. My original algorithm performed in O(n*k) time, right? Or is it O(n^k)? Am I correct that this algorithm is O(n*s)?

Comment: When you estimate the time-complexity of an algorithm, `k(number of queries)` should not be counted as a parameter. Which means the time-complexity of your original algorithm is **O(n)**.

Comment: Can you expand on this? It really seems like it should be... What if there were 10000 queries and 4 usernames?

Comment: When you have 10000 keyword to be queried, the algorithm is still called **"Finding matched username in total 4 usernames"** not **"Finding matched username in total 4 usernames for 10000 times"**. That why I say `number of queries` does not matter when you estimate the time-complexity of your algorithm. You can go to [Time-complexity page on wikipedia for more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).